# Según mi lógica este código debería ser así:.. ¿Por qué no funciona? - Python

Tags: python

El siguiente código (el de más abajo al final) el que **según yo** lo que debería hacer es mostrar la **suma de todos los números, desde el 1 hasta el número que ingrese el usuario**. Ejemplo: **El usuario ingresa el número 6, y debería mostrar como resultado muestra en pantalla que la suma de los números es 21. (Porque 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21).** Pero me da como respuesta **27**.

PD: Ya de como solucionarlo, es cambiando el orden de las variables **contador** y **acumulador** dentro del While. Quedando **acumulador** primero y **contador** después.

Pero no entiendo porque no funciona de la manera que **creo** que debería ser.

```py
contador = 1
acumulador = 0
maximo = int(input("Ingrese el número con el cual quiera sumar los anteriores: "))
while contador <= maximo:
    contador = contador + 1
    acumulador = acumulador + contador
print("La suma de los numeros es {}".format(acumulador))
```

Comment: el código que muestras no presenta fallos, muestra correctamente 21 al ingresar 6

Comment: Eso te muestra 27 por que en principio el contador es 1 y estas volviendo a sumar 1 antes de acumularlo, por eso te muestra un resultado incorrecta. Trata de ejecutar el ciclo en tu cabeza y verás que todo tiene sentido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pones la línea `contador = contador + 1` antes que la de `acumulador = acumulador + contador`, estarías empezando la suma en `2` y el último sumando sería `n+1`.

Por eso cuando `n = 6` el resultado es `27 = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7`.

Si las líneas las dejas como publicaste, la suma empieza en `1` y termina en `n`.